# JMeter - NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have a test in which I need to use Thread scheduling. For now I am using Ultimate Thread Group. But, then its throwing "NonGUI error" when I run the test -Is there a way where i can solve this issue? If not, can someone help me out how to do Thread schedule in non-GUI mode.

Note: My JMeter setup is in Kubernates server inside influxdb.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to install [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) plugins bundle before running your test. The recommended way of installing JMeter plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

Also be make sure to [upgrade to the latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) which is JMeter 5.0 as of now (check out [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page for the latest stable release)

If after the plugins installation you will still be experiencing problems - consider updating your question to include the generated XML otherwise no one will be able to help

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I wonder how i didn't thought about it at the 1st point of time. anyhow its the solution.